# Is there a way to fill in cell in excel based on array "x" number of times

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

I am trying to create a VBA script to fill cells in excel based on an array for X number of times.
The goal is to fill in the first array value for 50 times then, the next array value for 50 times and so on.
Currently I manage to get this working with the following code but it is filling only one cell and it is going to the next.
Does anybody know how to update this code and to make it to fill 50 cells with "55" then 50 cells with "66" ?
Thanks in advance !

```
Sub StaticArrayTest()
    Dim Myarray(1 To 3) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Myarray(1) = 55
    Myarray(2) = 66
    Myarray(3) = 77
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Myarray)
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Myarray(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. You need a couple more variables to keep track where your cells are and to loop through the iterations for each value:

```
Option Explicit
Sub StaticArrayTest()

    Dim Myarray(1 To 3) As Long 'Never use integer in Excel
    Myarray(1) = 55
    Myarray(2) = 66
    Myarray(3) = 77
    
    Dim NumberOfIterations As Long: NumberOfIterations = 50
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Position As Long: Position = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(Myarray)
        For j = 1 To NumberOfIterations
            Cells(Position, 1) = Myarray(i)
            Position = Position + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Fun little alternative:

```
Sub Test()  
    Range("A1:A150").Value = [CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(ROW(1:150)/50,0),55,66,77)]
End Sub
```

***Note:** Don't get fooled by how short this is written. It might prove harder to maintain and longer to run. Just throwing in another option though =)*

Answer (score 1):

I would do this slightly differently.

I would create a new array to hold all values and then write the array to the worksheet in ONE GO. Something like this. It also gives you the flexibility to change values with ease.

```
Option Explicit

Sub StaticArrayTest()
    Dim Myarray(1 To 3) As Long
    Myarray(1) = 55
    Myarray(2) = 66
    Myarray(3) = 77
    
    '~~> Number of iterations
    Dim slots As Long
    slots = 50
    
    '~~> Final array to hold values
    Dim finalArray() As Long
    ReDim finalArray(1 To slots * UBound(Myarray))
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    k = 1
    
    '~~> Populate the array
    For i = LBound(Myarray) To UBound(Myarray)
        For j = 1 To slots
            finalArray(k) = Myarray(i)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Write to the sheet in 1 go
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(finalArray), 1).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(finalArray)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Closer to OP's approach ...**

Your main issue was that you looped through the three array items by filling just one row range; defining a start range with a given offset will succeed and allows to reduce loop cycles:

```
Sub StaticArrayTestMe()
    '~~> Number of iterations
    Const slots As Long = 50
    '~~> values to insert repeatedly
    Dim Myarray(1 To 3) As Long
    Myarray(1) = 55
    Myarray(2) = 66
    Myarray(3) = 77
    
    With Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & slots)            ' refer to start range of 50 cells using the sheet's Code(Name)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(Myarray) To UBound(Myarray) ' here: 1st item to 3rd item
            'calculate new row offsets to start range: (1) 0, (2) 50, (3) 100
            .Offset((i - 1) * slots) = Myarray(i)  ' fill in 1st,2nd & 3rd item
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```